# Duplicate pointers after after erase from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have overloaded operator-=() to remove element (pointers are unique so there is no need to remove all occurrences, loop can be terminated once pointer is erased) from vector of pointers:

```
Rooms& Rooms::operator-=(Course *c) {
    for (Iter i = rooms.begin(); i != rooms.end(); ++i) {
        if (**i == *c) {
            *i = NULL;
            i = rooms.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The problem is that after applying to the vector I get duplicate pointers of the last element of vector. Before:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| POL | CAE | RUS | ENG | BUS | JPY |     |     |     |     |     |
| G 1 | G 1 | G 2 | G 2 | G 2 | G 2 |     |     |     |     |     |
|   9 |   9 |  10 |  10 |  10 |  10 |     |     |     |     |     |
```

After removing ENG & BUS:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| POL | CAE | RUS | JPY | JPY | JPY |     |     |     |     |     |
| G 1 | G 1 | G 2 | G 2 | G 2 | G 2 |     |     |     |     |     |
|   9 |   9 |  10 |  10 |  10 |  10 |     |     |     |     |     |
```

What should be changed to actually get result as:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| POL | CAE | RUS | JPY |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| G 1 | G 1 | G 2 | G 2 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   9 |   9 |  10 |  10 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My printing function looks like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Rooms& rs) {
    std::vector<std::string> output(3);
    std::ostringstream temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < rs.rooms.capacity(); ++i) {
        if (rs.rooms[i]) {
            temp << "| " << rs.rooms[i]->getCode() << " ";
            output[0] += temp.str();
            temp.str("");
            temp << "| G" << std::setw(CODE_LENGTH - 1)
                 << rs.rooms[i]->getGroup() << " ";
            output[1] += temp.str();
            temp.str("");
            temp << "| " << std::setw(CODE_LENGTH)
                 << rs.rooms[i]->getSize() << " ";
            output[2] += temp.str();
            temp.str("");
        } else {
            output[0] += "|     ";
            output[1] += "|     ";
            output[2] += "|     ";
        }
    }
    output[0] += "|";
    output[1] += "|";
    output[2] += "|";
    out <<  printHorizont(rs.size) << output[0] << std::endl
        << output[1] << std::endl << output[2] << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Looks complicated, but couldn't find better way of printing it way I want.

Comment: why this : `i =` rooms.erase(i); ?

Comment: @Hacketo The iterator that is erased becomes invalidated. `erase` returns a valid iterator to the element that used to be behind the erased one. OP: This code will skip elements if two erasable elements appear directly behind each other, but it should shorten the vector. Is it possible that the code that uses the vector after all this doesn't check for the changed length?

Comment: @Hacketo otherwise I get segmentation fault while printing the results. In printing function I use rooms[i] to access the elements.

Comment: Please show how you call the function? How do you figure out you get duplicate entries?

Comment: How do you print the result after removal? Isn't `rooms.size()` shrunk after `rooms.erase(i)`?

Comment: @Wintermute All pointers in vectors should be unique, so I need to erase only the first occurrence which should be also the only one. Btw. by erase I need to change only the size of vector, not the capacity (it has to be constant!).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Before adding new element to vector I check if element that I'm adding has the same code (snd line of output) and group num (third line). If so, I'm not adding it to the vector. So it kinda complicate things If I get those duplicated pointers

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - The issue is that you should use algorithm functions such as `find_if`, `remove_if`, etc. instead of loops like this.  Then your errors in general won't happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie remove_if sounds good, will give it a try and check if the same error happens again. Is there a standard build-in predicate for checking equality?

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - You are testing the dereferenced pointers.  So a `find_if` with a lambda, plus a call to erase with the returned value of `find_if` would be equivalent to your code (and all without the loop).

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk - `Iter i = std::find_if(rooms.begin(), rooms.end(), [](Course* pC){return *pC == *c; }); if ( i != rooms.end() )   rooms.erase(i);   return *this; `  Something to this effect.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have already started looking for the solution based on you previous comment. I've tried to avoid C++ 11, as I don't know it yet, but I think I will give it a shoot this time.

Comment: Firstly, as @Hacketo suggested, you are not using `i` after assigning to it the result of `rooms.erase(i)`. Also, why first store a null there and then erase the element? That said, take a look at `std::set<>`, which is a container that guarantees that elements are unique. You are reinventing the wheel and probably for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `operator<<()`,

```
for (int i = 0; i < rs.rooms.capacity(); ++i) {
```

For `rs.rooms.size() <= i < rs.rooms.capacity()`, basically `rs.rooms[i]` is illegal.

Use iterators to go through the vector, and you'll never make such a fault. If you really need to print those "empty spaces", you could write as

```
for (int i = 0; i < rs.rooms.capacity(); ++i) {
    if (i < rs.rooms.size() && rs.rooms[i]) {
        // access rs.rooms[i]
    } else {
        // print empty placeholder
    }
}
```

Comment: This is saying the bug is in your print routine and not your operator -= code,  Change capacity() to size() in your print routine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I have a question thou. As I need to print the empty spaces too, will iterator end after the last non-empty item or after last element given by capacity?

Comment: The iterator ends after the last logically non-empty item.

Comment: So in case of using iterator i will not be able to print the empty slots.

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk I updated the answer for you to avoid accessing illegal addresses while printing out what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks good now. I need those empty spaces as Rooms objects are a part of timetable.

Comment: Andrzej, forget about `vector::capacity()` for now. This and `vector::reserve()` are tools for optimizing things like reallocations, they don't have anything to do with managing the actual content of the vector. Actually, the only case where it doesn't just change the performance is when you use it to avoid iterator invalidation during reallocations, but that again is something that you shouldn't concern yourself with as a beginner.